# Overall score in cross-validation

Tags: regression, python, cross-validation, r-squared

I am using Repeated K-folds (`RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=10, random_state=999)` from sklearn) to provide reliable scores for a linear regression on my dataset.

The dataset has some outliers which should stay and also similar cases can be seen in future observations. When a trained data in a fold tries to predict such observations, I get negative scores (at least, this is my interpretation)

**Question**: the main question is what should I do with one (or a few) bad score(s) out of many? How should I report them and how useful would that be? 
Using 10 splits and 10 repeats for a data of size ~3000 observations, I will get 100 r-squared scores which are all in a good range (`0.97` to `0.99`). There is only one guy ruining the game and the score is so bad (`-11535`) that I cannot even get an average!

`[ 9.87345591e-01  9.73912516e-01  ... -1.15353090e+04 ...  9.72986827e-01]`

What shall I do in this case? how to report it and/or how to cure it?

Comment: cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/60927/55122